# add every combination between two vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

I have two vectors of unequal length:

---

```
vector1 <- c(1,2)
vector2 <- c(1,2,3)
```

I would like to add every character to every other character and output  a matrix that would look something like:

---

```
2,3,4
3,4,5
```

My actual vectors are quite large so I would need an approach that would be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `outer`, which would be more efficient for bigger vectors

```
outer(vector1, vector2, `+`)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    3    4
#[2,]    3    4    5
```

---

Or another option is `rep`

```
matrix(rep(vector1, each = length(vector2)) + vector2, 
            nrow = length(vector1), byrow = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `sapply`

```
sapply(vector2, `+`, vector1)
```